# Update multiple products in shopping cart

Tags: php

I am updating the cart using the following code but this code is updating the cart for a single product. How can I update the cart for multiple products?

**update.php** *(this page is to take input in text box i.e. the quantity )*

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>
<body>
    <form action="update1.php" method="post">
        Quantity:
        <input type="text" name="qty" value="">
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**update1.php** *(this code is to update the quantity of the cart)*

```
// foreach ( $value as $key=> $final_val ){
foreach($value as $product)
{
    if($_REQUEST['pro_id'] == $product['pro_id'])
    {     
        $found = true;
        break;
    }
}

if($found)
{
    $_SESSION['cart'][$_REQUEST['pro_id']]['qty'] ;
    $_SESSION[$x]=$product['qty'];
    $_SESSION["$qty"] = $_SESSION[$x]+$qty1;
    echo "qty:".$_SESSION["$qty"]; 
}
else
{
    // go get new product and add to $_SESSION['cart']
    echo"not done";
}
//}

echo "<h4 align='center'>  click here to <a href='shoppingcart.php'>see list</a> </h4>";
?>
```

Comment: This form doesn't seem to jive with your update code. You have `$_REQUEST['pro_id']` in the update code, but no `<input type="hidden" name="pro_id" value="whatever" />` (or similar) in your form. Also, elaborate on "multiple products." Multiple products at one time in one form or one form that can update multiple/different products on the site?

Comment: thanks for your reply...i need one form that can update multiple products..

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not 100% sure what you mean, so I will give you a simple demonstration of multiple in one form. You may or may not have a class or functions for your cart so I have made a very simple one for demonstration purposes. You would need to make your inputs arrayed on your form.

**/classes/ShoppingCart.php**

```
<?php
class   ShoppingCart
    {
        public  function initialize()
            {
                if(!isset($_SESSION['cart']))
                    $_SESSION['cart']   =   array();
            }

        public  function addToCart($id,$qty = 1)
            {
                if(empty($_SESSION['cart'][$id]))
                    $_SESSION['cart'][$id]  =   $qty;
                else
                    $_SESSION['cart'][$id]  +=  $qty;
            }

        public  function resetItem($id,$qty = 1)
            {
                $_SESSION['cart'][$id]  =   $qty;
            }

        public  function removeItem($id,$qty = false)
            {
                if(!$qty || !is_numeric($qty)) {
                    if(isset($_SESSION['cart'][$id]))
                        unset($_SESSION['cart'][$id]);
                }
                else {
                    if(empty($_SESSION['cart'][$id]))
                        return false;

                    $amt    =   ($_SESSION['cart'][$id] - $qty);

                    if($amt <= 0)
                        unset($_SESSION['cart'][$id]);
                    else
                        $_SESSION['cart'][$id]  =   $amt;
                }
            }

        public  function getItem($id)
            {
                return (!empty($_SESSION['cart'][$id]))? $_SESSION['cart'][$id] : 0;
            }

        public  function clearCart()
            {
                if(isset($_SESSION['cart']))
                    unset($_SESSION['cart']);
            }
    }
```

**/update.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
// Using spl_autoload_register() would be better than manual include
require_once(__DIR__.'/classes/ShoppingCart.php');
// Start the cart
$cartEngine =   new ShoppingCart();
?>
<html>
<body>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="update" />
        <ul>
            <li>
                <h4>Product 1</h4>
                QTY<input type="text" name="item[1][qty]" value="<?php echo $cartEngine->getItem('ITM1'); ?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="item[1][prod_id]" value="ITM1" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <h4>Product 2</h4>
                QTY<input type="text" name="item[2][qty]" value="<?php echo $cartEngine->getItem('ITM2'); ?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="item[2][prod_id]" value="ITM2" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <h4>Product 3</h4>
                QTY<input type="text" name="item[3][qty]" value="<?php echo $cartEngine->getItem('ITM3'); ?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="item[3][prod_id]" value="ITM3" />
            </li>
        </ul>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="clear" />
        <input type="submit" value="CLEAR CART" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This gives you an array on submission:

```
Array
(
    [action] => update_cart
    [item] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [qty] => 1
                    [prod_id] => ITM1
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [qty] => 2
                    [prod_id] => ITM2
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [qty] => 1
                    [prod_id] => ITM3
                )

        )

    [submit] => Submit
)
```

I personally would just not have a whole new page for the processing unless you are doing ajax. I would stick this part at the top of the page and reload the same page, but that is just me. To process the array would be something like:

```
// Using spl_autoload_register() would be better than manual include
require_once(__DIR__.'/classes/ShoppingCart.php');
// Start the cart
$cartEngine =   new ShoppingCart();
// See if action happens
if(!empty($_POST['action'])) {
    // Start the cart
    $cartEngine->initialize();
    // Do the cart stuff
    switch($_POST['action']) {
        case('update'):
            foreach($_POST['item'] as $item) {
                $cartEngine->resetItem($item['prod_id'],$item['qty']);
            }
            break;
        case('clear'):
            $cartEngine->clearCart();
            break;
    }
}
```

The cart would just be simple (you could make it more complicated if you want to by storing more data than just quantity and item code) but this is for demonstration, this would output a simple array like:

```
[cart] => Array
    (
        [ITM1] => 1
        [ITM2] => 2
        [ITM3] => 4
    )
```